# How to format my output of List of arrays c#

Tags: c#

I have a nested foreach loop. I want to display the results like this:

```
TIME  -  TITLE  -  DESCRIPTION
TIME2 -  TITLE2 -  DESCRIPTION2
```

**The loop:**

```
foreach (string[] array in log)
{
    foreach (string element in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

But currently the result is like this:

```
TIME
TITLE
DESCRIPTION
```

How can I format this the arrays in my List goes on the same line? And when the first array it goes on the second line and so forth?

Comment: It looks like you are asking to implement [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) feature. Check the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to output your strings in the manner you've asked for you need to know how much padding to add to each string to ensure that the `-` characters line up. The first column, in your sample text, has a maximum of 5 characters, so the first column in the first line needs to have an extra space added to make the `-` character line up before the second column starts, etc.

So, first you need to work out the `max_lengths` of each column:

```
var max_lengths =
    log
        .SelectMany(array =>
            array.Select((e, i) => new { length = e.Length, index = i }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.index, x => x.length)
        .Select(x => new { index = x.Key, max_length = x.Max() })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.max_length);
```

That gives:

[image: max_lengths]

Now you can create a version of `log` that has the padded strings:

```
var padded =
    log.Select(array =>
        array.Select((e, i) => e.PadRight(max_lengths[i])));
```

Now the result is simply this:

```
var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, padded.Select(x => String.Join(" - ", x)));
```

Which is:

```
TIME  - TITLE  - DESCRIPTION 
TIME2 - TITLE2 - DESCRIPTION2
```

We can test this with a more interesting set of inputs:

```
var log = new []
{
    new [] { "TIME", "TITLE", "DESCRIPTION" },
    new [] { "Happy Days", "Super Fun", "Woah!" },
    new [] { "Yes", "I can't complain", "simply stunning" },
};
```

That gives:

```
TIME       - TITLE            - DESCRIPTION    
Happy Days - Super Fun        - Woah!          
Yes        - I can't complain - simply stunning
```

Answer (score -1):

Append values in a string in any format you want to and then display that string.
For e.g

```
String s = s + element;

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

With `Console.Write(element + " - ");` you can write various elements in one line. After every element there is a " - " so they are seperated.
In the outer loop you want to have `Console.WriteLine();` to break to a new Line for your next elements.

Only Problem with this: You will have " - " at the end of your elements. Looking like:

```
TIME - TITLE - DESCRIPTION -
```

*Thanks to @Roma*

You could edit your loop like this:

```
foreach (string[] array in log)
{
    foreach (string element in array)
    {
        Console.Write(element + " - ");
    }
Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The Output should look like:

```
TIME  -  TITLE  -  DESCRIPTION  -
TIME2 -  TITLE2 -  DESCRIPTION2 -
```

Comment: You will have `-` at the end: `TIME  -  TITLE  -  DESCRIPTION - `

Comment: Thank you for that hint. It's something i did not think about. I'll edit my answer and remind everyone

Comment: You know that the output you've shown isn't what your code produces?

Answer (score -1):

A very simple apporach is [joining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) the string:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", array));
```

The result is exactly a string like `TIME  -  TITLE  -  DESCRIPTION` you expected.

Comment: why to add `using System.Linq`? You don't use it in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say that array list like :

```
List<string[]> arrayList = new List<string[]>
    {
       new string[] { "TIME1", "TITLE1" ,"DESCRIPTION1"},
       new string[] { "TIME2", "TITLE2" ,"DESCRIPTION2" }

     };
```

then foreach loop will be like :

```
foreach (string[] array in arrayList)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(array[0] + " - " + array[1] + " - "+ array[2]);   
}
```

output

```
TIME1 - TITLE1 - DESCRIPTION1
TIME2 - TITLE2 - DESCRIPTION2
```